# Disabling AMT via cmd (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-7, amt

I am an IT technician at a university. We are trying to disable Intel AMT on all of our computers due to a security vulnerability.

I tried to follow the steps in this [Mitigation Guide](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/26754/eng/Intel-SA-00075%20Mitigation%20Guide-Rev%201.2.pdf) but ran into a problem in the first step.

In an administrator CMD, I ran the following command (step 1 in guide):

ACUConfig.exe UnConfigure

This created a log file which ended with these two messages:

1. (ERROR) : ACU Configurator , Category: Error message: The Intel(R) Management Engine Interface driver is not installed or cannot be accessed. (0xc000001f)
2. (WARN) : ACU Configurator, Category: Exit: ***********Exit with code 2 - Intel(R) AMT is already unconfigured on this system.

I also tried the following command:

ACUConfig.exe UnConfigure /AdminPassword
"password" /Full

but the result was identical.

I restarted the computer and entered the AMT settings; AMT was still enabled.

Any ideas? 
Any other way to disable it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the next bit of the guide? "If these steps are unable to be performed, you alternately can try our posted “INTEL-SA-00075 Unprovisioning Tool” to perform the un-provisioning."

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the driver is installed, and you run this as an admin.